# Microphone only works in default browser and no other programs

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, audio, microphone

I'm on Windows 10 and have tried restarting and shutting down my laptop several times already.

My internal microphone, and my headset mic, only work(s) in my default browser, Google Chrome. The microphones do not work in Zoom, Discord, Voice Recorder, Audacity, or Microsoft Edge. The microphone used to work fine, and I don't know what changed. I noticed this problem after I first plugged in my Logitech headset (which has a microphone). Audacity records a very loud, constant buzz from the Logitech headset but no other programs get this -- they just receive a flat waveform. The Logitech headset, as well as the laptop's built-in mic work absolutely fine in the browser, so I don't know what the problem is.

I've checked my privacy settings and all the apps that I've tested on are allowed access to the microphone.

Thank you for any help!

P.S. The speakers and headset speakers work fine everywhere, if that's any help.

Comment: Did you update/reinstall your audio driver? Run the laptop manufacturer’s Driver update app.  Also please attend to other questions you have asked and not followed up on.

Comment: Also try updating the Microphone using Device Manager (Control Panel)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have not tried updating the microphone using Device Manager, but I have installed all the updates that I saw in System Settings -> Updates & Security -> Driver Updates. I'll go follow up on my other question post-haste! Thanks again!

Comment: When updating the built-in microphone in Device Manager, I got the following message: "Windows has determined that the best driver for this device has already been installed. There may be better drivers on Windows Update or on the device manufacturer's website." I have looked under Windows Update, and (as I wrote in my previous comment) all the drivers shown under Windows Update are up to date.

Comment: At this point, you should consider a Windows 10 Repair Install.  https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10

Windows 10 is running, so click on the Download button (not Upgrade Button) and select Run.  Use the option to Keep Everything.

Comment: Doing this, as long as I "Keep Everything", will not damage any of my files or apps/programs, correct?

Comment: Correct. Keep Everything does just that. It leaves you where you were.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem. Funnily enough, after messing around so long trying so many different fixes it was very simple.

I had my main, built-in laptop speakers muted at 0% volume. When I put it up to 1% volume my microphones all started working again completely normally. The volume of the built-in speakers does not appear to change the recording volume unless they are completely off.

If you are experiencing this issue, try turning your laptop's built-in speakers up to anywhere from 1%-100% volume.